# Build Rest API is ignoring "demands"

Tags: powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to queue a build following this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0

I would like to queue the build using a specific agent. The JSON body goes through properly but "demands" is not being incorporated and chooses the most available agent in the pool.

```
$body = @{
    ...
    ...
    "demands" = @(@{
       "value" = "Agent.Name -equals agent.01"
    })
}
```

I also tried:

```
    "demands" = @(@{
       "name" = "Agent.Name"
       "value" = "agent.01"
    })

    "demands" = @(
       "Agent.Name -equals agent.01"
    })
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe demands are broken, at least for on-prem Server 2020, Update 1.2.  After beating my head against the wall for longer than I care to admit, I came up with a workaround: add a parameter to the pipeline YAML, and set the pool demands: value based on that parameter.

### Pipeline YAML:

```
parameters:
- name: buildAgent

stages:
- stage: StageName
  jobs:
  - job: JobName
    pool: 
      name: Default
      demands: Agent.Name -equals ${{ parameters.buildAgent }}
    steps: ...
```

### API request body:

```
{
   "definition": {"id": "123"},
   "templateParameters": {"buildAgent":"*agentnamegoeshere*"}
}
```

Edited to add: the pool (with demand) can theoretically go on the stage or pipeline, mine just happened to be on the job, and that's the way I tested it.